# How to solve the non-linear equation $-(a+c\,e)\left(\exp(-b/(a+c\,e))-1\right)-c\,d=f$ for $c$?

Tags: roots, transcendental-equations

I have this non linear equation:
$$-(a+c\,e)\left(e^{-\frac{b}{a+c\,e}}-1\right)-c\,d=f$$
The only unknown is $c$.
All the coefficients ($a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, $f$) are real non-null costants.

How can I find $c$? Do you have some idea?

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you do with an equation like that, is to get rid of extra complexity. Put $x=b/(a+ce^1)$, then the equation for the new unknown $x$ has the form $$e^{-x}=\alpha+\beta x$$ where you can express $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in terms of the other parameters of the problem. This is a transcendental equation with no solution in terms of simple functions. Your best bet is most likely to solve it numerically. You can also express the solution in terms of [Lambert's W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), but depending on what you need this for, that might well be overkill.

Comment: You can also find out more about the Lambert W by searching this site.

Comment: \beta parameter depends of c.

Comment: @marchetto Then you made a mistake in your calculation. I just redid the calculation myself by hand, and verified with Maple. I get $\alpha=1-d/e$ and $\beta=ad/(bc)-f/b$.

Comment: Uh, make that $\beta=ad/(be)-f/b$. In the present context, an unfortunate typo.

Comment: Yes I made a mistake.