# Non-linear system of exponential equations with 2 boundary conditions: $p(y_m)=p_m$ and $\frac{dp(y)}{dy}$

Tags: systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

I have this equation:
$$
p(y) = -\left(e^{-\tfrac{K_{py}zy}{p_u+c e}}-1\right)\left(p_u+c e^1\right)-c\left(1-e^{-y}\right)^d\left(e^1-e^{1-y}\right)
$$
The two unknowns are $c$ and $d$ and the system that I want to solve is:
\begin{cases}
p(y_m) = p_m\\
\\
\dfrac{\mathrm{d}p(y)}{\mathrm{d}y}\Bigg|_{y = y_m} = 0
\end{cases}

I already seen what you suggest in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1042718/how-to-solve-the-non-linear-equation-ac-e-left-exp-b-ac-e-1-right) but again I don't understand how to solve the problem even with [Lambert's W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).  Considering that all the quantities are real constant and the following variables are $y\geq0$, $y_m>0$, $p_u\geq0$, $p_m\geq p_u$, does exist an exact solution? Can you help me to find it?

Thank you for your kind cooperation.